# Docker + Redis - fails to run command

Tags: docker, redis

First time trying `docker` with `Laravel sail`.

On first `sail up` I noticed the following error:

```
WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition
```

I followed [instructions here](https://r-future.github.io/post/how-to-fix-redis-warnings-with-docker/) to fix this issue, but I am now stuck with this error:

```
sh: ./init.sh: not found
```

My dir structure is:

```
e:\laravel-project
   - docker-compose.yml

e:\Docker
   $redis
      - Dockerfile
      - init.sh
      - redis.conf
```

My `docker-compose` contains:

```
redis:
    build:
        context: "./../../Docker/Redis"
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "redis:alpine"
    privileged: true
    command: sh -c "./init.sh"
    ports:
        - "${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379"
    volumes:
        - "sail-redis:/data"
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

My `Dockerfile` (from the link) is:

```
# file: docker/redis/Dockerfile
FROM redis:alpine
WORKDIR /redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
COPY init.sh ./
RUN chmod +x init.sh
```

The `init.sh` file contains:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag

sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=512
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --bind 0.0.0.0
```

The first error is not showing now which leads me to think the `redis.conf` file is being loaded.

`redis` exist with error and does not start:

```
exited with code 127
```

What have I missed on the `init.sh` file? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to connect to the built insane and check for the path of redis.conf and init.sh?

Comment: Hi Sergio, first time using Docker. Not sure what you mean by "built insane" but the `redis` container fails to load with `exited with code 127` so I cannot access its cli (if this is what you meant).

Comment: Can you try to build it manually? `docker build -t myredis .` in the Dockerfile folder. Then if success, run it `docker run --rm myredis`

Comment: Thanks. Running `docker build -y myredis .` (should this be `redis`?) errors with `=> CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore` and `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount111464106/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Comment: Please take a look at the build command. You need to build your image to understand where it is failing. You used -y it must be -t which is a tag name for your built image. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: Sorry, I used `-t` but typed it wrong in my reply to you.